# VS 2010 is missing CrystalReportViewer after Crystal is installed

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I installed Crystal Reports for VS 13.0.2000 to work with VS 2010. I will need to use CR in a WinForm app.

To my utter surprise, I have **no** CrystalReportViewer in my VS Toolbox pane for WinForms. The CrystalReportViewer **does** show up in Toolbox for web forms though.

I could obviously add the viewer to my winform without using the toolbox, but I can not seem to figure out what do I need to reference to get it. I am already referencing all the usual dll's like CrystalReports.Engine and CrystalDecisions.Shared but it does not help.

Does anybody have any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you're targeting the full framework, and not any subsets, such as the client profile